# OPENJSON - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Wondering if anyone can work out what's wrong with this, I keep getting this error when reading the table from another database other than [HubSpotCache] (still in the same SQL instance).

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

```
SELECT
    J.label
FROM
    [HubSpotCache].dbo.[ContactProperties] C
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(C.[OptionsAggregate])
    WITH (
            label NVARCHAR(100) N'$."value"'
         ) AS J
WHERE 
    ISJSON(C.[OptionsAggregate]) > 0
```

Here's the value in OptionsAggregate column of the table

```
[
  {
    "label": "China",
    "value": "China",
    "displayOrder": -1,
    "doubleData": 0.0,
    "hidden": false,
    "readOnly": false
  },
  {
    "label": "Singapore",
    "value": "Singapore",
    "displayOrder": -1,
    "doubleData": 0.0,
    "hidden": false,
    "readOnly": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Check the compatibility level of the databases: SELECT name,compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases  - it should be at least 130 for openjson to be implemented

Comment: Compatibility level is lower than 130, right click on the database, go to Options, and change the compatibility level to `SQL Server 2016 (130)` or higher.

Comment: It's SQL 2016, it works when the query runs in [HubSpotCache] database but not when it's from another database on the same SQL instance.

Comment: The title doesn't reflect the question. This has nothing to do with a CTE.

Comment: *"it works when the query runs in [HubSpotCache] database but not when it's from another database on the same SQL instance."* Then the database you're running the query on definitely has a compatibility setting that doesn't support the syntax you're using.

Comment: This is not a duplicate but [it's related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645938/sql-server-2014-type-date-is-not-a-defined-system-type/54648281#54648281)

Comment: Could this be the issue?  From this web page: If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server can't find and run the OPENJSON function.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 12):

Which version of SQL server you are using? If you have the right SQL Server version, then most likely it's the `Compatibility Level` as [OPENJSON requires Compatibility Level 130](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#openjson-requires-compatibility-level-130), so check your compatibility level,  if it is not 130 set it to 130 and  try

Comment: ```ALTER DATABASE <DatabaseName> SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130``` to set compatibility level